# Passing a GET parameter to ActionLink in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.actionlink

Sorry but I am new to C# and ASP.NET and I saw alot of posts about this problem but I quite didn't get it. I am trying to understand how to pass a GET parameter to an action thru HTML.ActionLink:

here is the the URL:

```
http://localhost:36896/Movies/SearchIndex?searchString=the
```

and my CSHTML page should look like this:

```
<input type="Text" id="searchString" name="searchString" />
@Html.ActionLink("Search Existing", "SearchIndex", new { searchString = "the"})
```

this hard coded parameter "the" is actually working, but how can I select the input element with id=searchString, with something like `document.getElementById("searchString").value`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes the @Html.EditorFor refer to the Title field of the object, kinda in a random way but it works!

```
@using (Html.BeginForm ("SearchIndex", "Movies", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.EditorFor( x => x.ElementAt(0).Title)
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
}
```

Still couldn't pass input parameter to the URL in the GET.

**EDIT**:

**FINAL SOLUTION**:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString")
    <button type="submit">Filter</button>
```

and on the controller side, switch the input parameter. Basically it will automatically recognize the passed parameter.

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
        {
           ...
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If the value you want to send as GET parameter is not known on the server you cannot use the Html.ActionLink helper to add it. You need to use javascript to manipulate the existing link and append the parameter.

It looks like you have an input field that contains a search string and you want to send the value entered in this field to the server. A better way to handle this scenario is to use an HTML form with method="GET" instead of an ActionLink. This way you don't need to use any javascript - it's part of the HTML specification:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchIndex", "Movies", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SearchString)
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
}
```

Now when you click on the `Search` button the value entered in the `SearchString` field will automatically be sent to the `SearchIndex` action:

```
http://localhost:36896/Movies/SearchIndex?searchString=the
```

But if you absolutely insist on using an ActionLink you will have to write javascript to manipulate the href of the existing link when this link is clicked in order to append the value to the url. It's an approach I wouldn't recommend though because the HTML specification already provides you this functionality throughout HTML forms.

Comment: Thank you thats clear and makes me understand how is easier that the way I wanted to do it, but I have one doubt, this was it doesn;t recognize the searchString parameter, underlining it as not defined

Comment: You mean the `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SearchString)` line? For this to work your view must be strongly typed to a view model a `SearchString` property. If you don't use view models and want to hardcode your HTML (totally not-recommended) you could use `<input type="text" name="searchString" />` inside the form.

Comment: the thing is I don't have a property searchString is the input type on the page, this value looked up in one of the fields of my objects this is how is decleared on the page ( @model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie> ) and the filed is Title

Comment: You should then define a view model that has 2 properties: the search string and the collection of movies and make your view strongly typed to this view model. If you need to search on this page then you must have a searchstring property on your view model => you have chosen the wrong type for view model.

Comment: Well my object has an attribute Title, and I'm stuck in how to  search in that field passing the search string in a GET parameter as searchString